# Where is a connection string specified in visual studio to connect SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, dynamics-365

I have a build server that fails to synchronize database due to the connection issue.

There is a build pipeline in Azure DevOps and one step is to sync database. When I'm trying to run synchronization locally(on the build server itself) from Visual Studio it also fails because cannot connect to database instance. From logs I can also see message like failed to connect.

I've checked `web.config` file as I thought that values for connecting to DB are stored there - but they're all fine, credentials, instance, server are set correctly.

I've tried to sync database with `Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Deployment.Setup.exe` utility providing explicitly path for packages and credentials for database and sync succeeded.

I think the problem is in setup of Visual Studio or on the build server itself that it cannot connect to DB any more, but no idea where do i change those values to make it work.

Comment: FYI, You don't connect to SSMS, you connect to SQL Server. SSMS is an IDE, just like Visual Studio. I **assume** you *have* installed SQL Server.

Comment: Where is your SQL Server? Is it on-premise - if so, Azure DevOps is unlikely to be able to connect to it...

Comment: it is a cloud onebox, so the environment itself is deployed in cloud but SQL server and studio are installed locally on that environment